# All usb c ports are working flawlessly but charging keeps flickering on and off in irregular basis

Tags: usb, battery, charging

This is a macbook pro 2018. All the usb ports are working with all other peripherals and the charger works also, but sometimes it keeps turning on and off (it keeps chiming to say it's charging, randomly, every minute or so) and sometimes it charges normally.

I tried to reset SCM and NVRAM. I'm thinking that this is a big sur thing and downgrade to catalina or the adapter is malfunctioning or maybe it is a logic board thing. What do you think?

Comment: I would try to find out what component ist failing. Test with another wall plug if the problem persists. Test with another cable if the problem persists. Test with another Mac/Device. Then move on to check whether its the Macs software by basically installing any other Mac version or maybe you installed windows with bootcamp. If you can make sure that some OS on this Mac doesn't create this problem, then its software. Otherwise it must the some component inside the Mac failing.

Comment: Do you have the charger connected with the AC mains extension cord, or is the charger directly plugged into a power socket?  Start at the weakest link, the charger cable and/or charger, and work from there. If you have access to a known-good charger, and it doesn't exhibit the sporadic chiming and has a solid LED when connected to your MBP, then your charger cable or the charger itself is at fault. I've seen charging cables which look absolutely undamaged, but yet have some invisible defect which prevents or presents odd behaviours whilst charging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the circuity of the power adaptor has some defects. Changed it and everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: Great you could solve the issue. Could you mark this answer as accepted? To do this click, the green check box by the answer. This shows other people your question has the answer you were looking for and will help others that have a similar issue.